# xcode does not recognise paymentcontext, it shows found nil unexpectedy

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

This is my simulator-
[image]

It shows - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value  in both the below scenarios:

i) - when I click on "card", it shows error as shown in the screenshot below:-
[image]

ii)when I click on "checkout" first it shows the following on the simulator[image]

when I click on "confirm, , it shows error as shown in the screenshot below:-
[image]

This is my "CheckoutVC" -

```
 import UIKit
 import Stripe
 import Firebase
  class CheckoutVC: UIViewController {
 var product = Cart()
  lazy  var quantitylabel = product.totalQuantity

   var Pro = Product(imagename:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "blue"), price: 5,unit: 5)

  @IBOutlet weak var selectCardView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var cardIcon: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var cardEndingIn: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var selectBankView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bankIcon: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var bankEndingIn: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!



  var currentSelectedPaymentType: PaymentType?
  var paymentContext: STPPaymentContext!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    setupStripe()
    setupTapGestures()
    setupUi()
    setCheckoutLabelDetails()
   }

   func setCheckoutLabelDetails() {
    let pricelabel = Pro.price.formatToCurrencyString()
    
    let processingFee = FeesCalculator.calculateFeesForCard(subtotal: Pro.price)
    let  formatprocessingfees = "Processing Fees: \(processingFee.formatToCurrencyString())"
    
    let total = processingFee + Pro.price
   let totallabel = "Total: \(total.formatToCurrencyString())"
    }

     func setupUi() {
   let   producttitle = Pro
    let productprice = Pro.price
   
    let qunatity = "\(Pro.unit) night accomodations"
    
  let price = Pro.price.formatToCurrencyString()
  }

func setupTapGestures() {
    let selectCardTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectCardTapped))
    selectCardView.addGestureRecognizer(selectCardTouch)
    
   
    let selectBankTouch = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectBankTapped))
    selectBankView.addGestureRecognizer(selectBankTouch)
}
@objc func selectBankTapped() {
   setBankPaymentView()
}
func setBankPaymentView() {
    if currentSelectedPaymentType == .bank { return }
    
    currentSelectedPaymentType = .bank
    
    selectBankView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: AppColor.BorderBlue)?.cgColor
    selectBankView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    
    selectCardView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    selectCardView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    
    bankIcon.tintColor = UIColor(named: AppColor.BorderBlue)
    cardIcon.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

func setupStripe() {
    
    guard (UserManager.instance.user?.stripeId) != nil else { return }
    
    let config = STPPaymentConfiguration.shared
    paymentContext = STPPaymentContext(customerContext: Wallet.instance.customerContext,
                                       configuration: config(),
                                       theme: .default())
    
    paymentContext.hostViewController = self
    paymentContext.delegate = self
    
}

// MARK: Select Card
@objc func selectCardTapped() {
   setCardPaymentView()
}
func setCardPaymentView() {
    if currentSelectedPaymentType == .card { return }
    
    currentSelectedPaymentType = .card
    
    selectCardView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: AppColor.BorderBlue)?.cgColor
    selectCardView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    
    selectBankView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    selectBankView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    
    cardIcon.tintColor = UIColor(named: AppColor.BorderBlue)
    bankIcon.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
}

@IBAction func changeCardClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    self.paymentContext.pushPaymentOptionsViewController()
}

@IBAction func changeBankClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
}

@IBAction func payBtnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let total = Pro.price + FeesCalculator.calculateFeesForCard(subtotal: Pro.price)

    let confirmPayment = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm Payment", message: "Confirm payment for \(total.formatToDecimalCurrencyString())", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.paymentContext.requestPayment()
    }
    
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
    
    confirmPayment.addAction(confirmAction)
    confirmPayment.addAction(cancel)
    present(confirmPayment, animated: true)
   }
 }

 extension CheckoutVC: STPPaymentContextDelegate {

  func paymentContextDidChange(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext) {
    // Triggers when the content of the payment context changes, like when the user selects a new payment method or enters shipping information.
    if let card = paymentContext.selectedPaymentOption {
        cardEndingIn.text = card.label
    } else {
        cardEndingIn.text = "No Card Selected"
    }
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error) {
    simpleAlert(msg: "Sorry, but we are not able to load you credit cards at this time.")
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPPaymentStatusBlock) {
            
    // Request Stripe payment intent, and return client secret.
    
    guard let stripeId = UserManager.instance.user?.stripeId else { return }
    
    let idempotency = UUID().uuidString.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    
    let fees = FeesCalculator.calculateFeesForCard(subtotal: Pro.price)
    let total = Pro.price + fees
    
    let data: [String: Any] = [
        "total": total,
        "idempotency": idempotency,
        "customer_id": stripeId
    ]
    
    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("createPaymentIntent").call(data) { (result, error) in
        
        if let error = error {
            debugPrint(error)
            self.simpleAlert(msg: "Sorry, but we are not able to complete your payment.")
            return
        }
        
        guard let clientSecret = result?.data as? String else {
            self.simpleAlert(msg: "Sorry, but we are not able to complete your payment.")
            return
        }
        
        // Once the client secret is obtained, create paymentIntentParams
        let paymentIntentParams = STPPaymentIntentParams(clientSecret: clientSecret)
        paymentIntentParams.paymentMethodId = paymentResult.paymentMethod.stripeId
        
        // Confirm the PaymentIntent
     
        STPPaymentHandler.shared().confirmPayment(withParams: paymentIntentParams, authenticationContext: paymentContext) { (status, paymentIntent, error) in
            
            switch status {
            
            case .succeeded:
                completion(.success, nil)
            case .failed:
                completion(.error, nil)
            case .canceled:
                completion(.userCancellation, nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didFinishWith status: STPPaymentStatus, error: Error?) {
    // Take action based on return status: error, success, userCancellation
    switch status {
    
    case .success:
        
        let successAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Payment Success!", message: "\nYou will receive an email with all the travel details soon! \n\n Bon Voyage!", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default) { (action) in
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        }
        
        successAlert.addAction(ok)
        present(successAlert, animated: true)
        
    case .error:
        simpleAlert(msg: "Sorry, something went wrong during checkout. You were not charged and can try again.")
        
    case .userCancellation:
        return
      }
    }
  }


   enum PaymentType {
    case card
    case bank
     }
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that `STPPaymentContext(customerContext:...)` is called?

Comment: +1 to the above; I think `UserManager.instance.user?.stripeId` is `nil` when `setupStripe()` is called so the `paymentContext` is never created.  Can you add logging to your `guard` statement to see if that's what's happening?

Comment: @JustinMichael - yes, i added loggng, it prints nil. does it have to do with other viewcontrolleres, right

Comment: I went to signupviecontroller, linked it with chekcoutvc with the segues, I signed up, it shows in the firebase console, still same error when i click on "card"

Comment: the user also still prints nil

Comment: i think the stripe user should also be signed in ?? right ???

Comment: It's hard to say based on what you've shared.  What does `UserManager.instance.user` contain at that point, is it the user you expect without `stripeId` populated, or is the user completely missing?